# How to create a navigation menu like this in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, menu, navigation-drawer

[image: Dcoder app screenshot in playstore]

How can I create a navigation menu like this for my app in android studio.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing that navigation bar from scratch will be bit difficult. What I suggest instead is to use a library for that purpose.

Here is a library that gives the same UI as you want, read this readme. It is called Duo-Navigation-drawer

https://github.com/PSD-Company/duo-navigation-drawer/blob/master/README.md

This readme file contains all the necessary steps to implement it on your app.
Give it a read.

While there are many other libraries too.

Here is a screenshot of the navigation bar.

[Click here to view](https://github.com/PSD-Company/duo-navigation-drawer/blob/master/dev/example.png)

Answer (score 1):

Create a navigation Drawer (with menu items), you can access full code here
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer